# ECL ContentLibraryItemContractToViewHostAdapter' casting ecxeption

Tags: ecl

After calling `IContentLibraryContext.GetItem()` and `IContentLibraryListItem.Id` for a Multimedia item (`EclItemTypes.File`) the Tridion CME throws the following error. The exception does not show up in Visual Studio while attaced to the `TcmServiceHost` process so I think something in the Tridion ECL ran into something unexpected.

I have compared the code against the Flickr example implementation but cannot find what I would do wrong. Any ideas why this error would pop up?

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryItemContractToViewHostAdapter'
>   to type
>   'Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostViews.IContentLibraryMultimediaItem'.

Error detail:

> StackTrace Information Details:
>   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.ItemDataBuilder.ToFullItemData(IContentLibraryItem item, String stubSchemaId, StubItemListData stubItemListData, IDictionary`2 displayTypes)
>   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.FileItemDataBuilder.BuildResultListItemData()
>   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetFile(EclUri eclUri, Func`3 getStubId, Action`1 stubItemManipulations, Nullable`1 openMode)
>   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetItem(String itemUri, Int32 openMode)
>   at SyncInvokeGetItem(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an item of the `File` type, make sure you return an instance of `IContentLibraryMultimediaItem` from `GetItem` and `GetItems`.

The exceptions can be a bit hard to read, as they originate from the code connecting the different versions of the contracts.

Comment: That's it!
I implemented `IContentLibraryItem` instead of `IContentLibraryMultimediaItem`.
The IContentLibraryMultimediaItem implements IContentLibraryItem which implements IContentLibraryListItem, that helps creating a clean implementation of all those items without having to duplicate a lot of code for getting parent ids and so on.

Comment: Yes, but then I'll have higher ranking than he does :)

Comment: Lars, you already have a higher reputation.